# ffmpeg - map a video to a placeholder? (rectangle/square)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that i want to map to a "virtual rectangle".
Meaning, i want to create a virtual rectangle by giving it one x,y point for the bottom left corner and one x,y point for the top right corner.

Given those 2 points would create a rectangle, i want to take that video and "map" it to that rectangle. (scale it too if necessary)

From what i know about the 'overlay' filter, you can use only one x,y point to set the position of the video.

But is there a way of doing it with 2 points like i explained?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the template below,

```
ffmpeg -i base.mp4 -i overlay.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=WxH[o];[0][o]overlay=x:y" out.mp4
```

So, the overlay video is scaled and then placed at `(x,y)` measured from top-left of base video and the opposite corner is at `(x+W, y+H)`

Comment: so that means i'd have to provide the scale width and height too right? it won't be done automatically

Comment: Yeah, but your desired scenario also requires four numbers. The last two happen to be different.

Comment: So i'd have to provide x1,y1 and W,H and only then i'd be able to get x2,y2? There's no way of inputing x1,y1 and x2,y2 and have the W,H calculated automatically?

Comment: No. It's the same thing though. Think of W as `x2-x1` and H as `y2-y1`

Comment: Haha you're right sorry.. thanks!! You save me every time when it comes to ffmpeg ;)